# Detect only a rotation gesture from right to left

Tags: ios, rotation, gesture, right-to-left

I was able to detect a rotation gesture, but I only need to detect the one from right to left.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean accelerometer events triggered by physically rotating the device? Or do you mean some touch gesture that is rotating something on the screen? Both are discussed in the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1). If you need more help after reviewing that guide, please clarify precisely what kind of "rotation gesture" you mean.

Comment: I meant the touch gesture. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using UIRotationGestureRecognizer to detect rotation. You should have something like this:

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureRecognizerAction:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and:

```
- (void)gestureRecognizerAction:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  if (gestureRecognizer.rotation > 0) {
     //rotation in one side - lets say from left to right
  } else {
     //rotation in other side - lets say from right to left
  }
}
```

In this way you will be able to detect only the rotation from right to left.

Comment: Thanks Rafal! I was missing the rotation method for the gestureRecognizer object.